# R program to take a variable name from a function [edited]

Tags: r, function

This seems quite easy. But I am stuck for an hour or more.

```
function(directory, pollutant , id = 1:332)
```

I want to take the value of pollutant say it is 'nitrate'.

My data is assigned to variable 'mydata'

```
mydata$nitrate[ "some condition"]
```

But I have to pass it like

```
mydata$pollutant . How could I assign the value from pollutant with $ .
```

Is there any way to do this.

Comment: Why not use `mydata[[pollutant]]` instead of using `$`?

Comment: @MatthewLundberg . But I have to add some conditions inside it. Like I have to select only portion of data$nitrate[data$ID>=5) & data$ID <=10]

Comment: @user3116355 Why don't you provide some sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `[[` rather than `$`.  Each returns the element itself (as opposed to a list containing the element).  For your use, these are equivalent (`$` allows abbreviations, but this isn't an issue here).

To address your comment:

```
mydata[[pollutant]][mydata$ID >= 5 & mydata$ID <= 10]
```

Comment: I have tried the same . But it returns me a NULL list